# Ansible run shell module on multiple host's and redirect output to 1 file

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts, ansible-template

I need to run shell module on all hosts group and copy the register variable to a file on any server.
NOTE : I don't want to copy the results in my local i need it on server

```yaml
- name: date.
  shell: cat /ngs/app/user/test
  register: date_res
  changed_when: false
- debug:
    msg: "{{ ansible_play_hosts | map('extract', hostvars, 'date_res') | map(attribute='stdout') | list }}"
  run_once: yes
  
- name: copy bulk output
  copy:
    content: "{{ allhost_out.stdout }}"
    dest: "/ngs/app/{{ app_user }}/test"
```

Comment: Why don't you use `when: inventory_hostname == blabla.example.com` on the last task?

Comment: Even if you use inventory_hostname == blabla.example.com , it copys only a particular host data on the host, but the requirement is to copy all host results to a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jinja2 loop can be helpful for your case.
Tested on `ansible [core 2.13.3]`

```yaml
- name: date.
  shell: cat /ngs/app/user/test
  register: date_res
  changed_when: false
  
- name: copy bulk output
  copy:
    content: |
        {% for host in vars['play_hosts'] %}
        {{ host }} {{ hostvars[host].date_res.stdout }}
        {% endfor %}
    dest: "/ngs/app/{{ app_user }}/bldall"
  when: inventory_hostname == host-001.example.com
```

On `host-001.example.com` placed a file contains: `host1 file content`.
On `host-002.example.com` placed a file contains: `host2 file content`.
Output on host specified in the copy task:

```yaml
host-001.example.com host1 file content
host-002.example.com host2 file content
```

Comment: Wow its working the way i want it , last question along with content i need to print host name some thing like below please help.  `content: "{{ ansible_play_hosts | map('extract', hostvars, 'date_res','inventory_hostname') | map(attribute='stdout') | list }}"`.       . This is not working

Comment: You're trying to extract the hostname from the output date_res, which isn't right. Use `"{{ ansible_play_hosts | map('extract', hostvars, 'inventory_hostname') }}"` instead.

Comment: I need to print first hostaname and then date_res so i need both variable inside map.    ERROR : `"msg": "template error while templating string: unexpected ','. String: {{ ansible_play_hosts | map('extract', hostvars, ,'inventory_hostname','allhost_out') | map(attribute='stdout_lines') | list"`.                   Used : `msg: "{{ ansible_play_hosts | map('extract', hostvars, ,'inventory_hostname','allhost_out') | map(attribute='stdout_lines') | list"`

Comment: The code which is giving for jinga2 loop is working magically right. thanks for taking so much time to explain this in very simplest way. i understood every part of the loop. i would like to say this code worked in more 1000 host's and results were successfully matching. thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: `- name: gather information of all host
    shell: find /ngs/app/user/logs/binary_results/{{ bld }}/*/*.json -type f -mtime -10 -exec ls -lrt {} \;
    register: allhost_out
    ignore_errors: yes
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_play_hosts | map('extract', hostvars, 'allhost_out') | map(attribute='stdout_lines') | list }}"
    run_once: yes`.             ERROR.                               The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: None is undefined.              The offending line appears to be:

    ignore_errors: yes
  - debug:
    ^ here